# How to close a Navbar Dropdownmenu when opening another one?

Tags: python, bootstrap-5, plotly-dash

I added multiple [dropdownmenus](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/dropdown_menu/) to a [navbar](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/).
When activating both one after another, both stay open:

[image]

How can I configure the navbar or the dropdownmenu to automatically close the first dropdownmenu upon opening the second one?

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.DARKLY])

navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
    children=[
        dbc.DropdownMenu(
            children=[dbc.DropdownMenuItem("How to")],
            nav=True,
            in_navbar=True,
            label="Here is",
        ),
        dbc.DropdownMenu(
            children=[dbc.DropdownMenuItem("auto-close?")],
            nav=True,
            in_navbar=True,
            label="my question",
        ),
    ],
)


# embedding the navigation bar
app.layout = html.Div([navbar])

app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=80)
```

Comment: This is working fine on my side (chrome, dash and dbc latest).

Comment: @EricLavault Thanks for your tests! The error indeed seems to be connected to this particular machine. On another computer, I get the expected behaviour. I will try to find out the differences to get to the root cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs due to an outdated version 1.0.0 of dash_bootstrap_components (dbc). As mentioned in the [changelog](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/changelog/), this was fixed in version 1.0.1:

> Fixed regressions in DropdownMenu dismissal. The menu will dismiss if
> the user clicks outside the menu or if the escape key is pressed.

Upgrading dbc to the latest version resulted in the expected auto-closure.